# DataFrame method for renaming axis

Tags: python, pandas

I commonly rename the index and/or the column to keep track of the layout in a dataframe (not the *values* in the column, but the column itself). The only way I know is by explicitly setting the attribute.

```
np.random.seed(10); a = np.random.randint(0, 20, (3, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.columns.name = 'A'
df.index.name = 'B'
df
    A   0   1
    B        
    0   9   4
    1  15   0
    2  17  16
```

Is there a `DataFrame` or `Series` method to perform this that would enable method-chaining (i.e., that would look like `df.rename(column='A', index='B').[...other method calls]`)? I would have expected this functionality in [`.rename()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html), but it doesn't seem to have this option.

Comment: The `Index` object `name` attribute is `None` by default you have to explicitly set this, it's possible to pass this in the ctor for a [`Index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) or use [`set_names`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.set_names.html#pandas.Index.set_names)

Comment: So this would work: `df.columns.set_names('A', inplace=True)
df.index.set_names('B', inplace=True)`

Comment: Thanks @EdChum, that's useful to know. I tried to edit it to make it clearer, but I'm looking for a method that's a member of a DataFrame or Series, rather than Index.

Comment: it doesn't exist AFAIK not sure there is much call for this seeing as dfs always has an index and columns attribute

Comment: yeah you can't do it, this is also a pet peeve of mine, you should add it as a pull request for pandas if you have the time

Comment: @maxymoo I created an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11965) for it to gauge interest

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe such method exists. But hey, add it, if you need it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class DF(pd.DataFrame):

    def rename_columns(self,name):
        self.columns.name = name
        return self

    def rename_index(self,name):
        self.index.name = name
        return self

np.random.seed(10); a = np.random.randint(0, 20, (3, 2))
df = DF(a)
df.rename_columns('egg').rename_index('bacon')
df
```

[image: dataframe with changed columns and index]

Answer (score 0):

Such a method does exist.

Use `df.rename_index('new_column_name', axis=0, inplace=True)` to rename `df.index`. (Change `axis=0` to `axis=1` to rename `df.columns` instead.)

#### More detail

Sometime before Pandas Version 1, the functions `df.rename` and `df.rename_index` had overlapping functionality. Now `df.rename_index` is used to rename the entire `df.index` (or `df.columns`), while `df.rename` is used to change particular entries in the index (or names or particular columns).

Similarly-named methods exist for `Series` objects, but they work slightly differently.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I ran into the same question and it looks like the [issue opened in the pandas repo](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11965) has been completed.

There now is a `rename_axis` method on the `Dataframe` object that now enables to give name(s) to index level(s) and can be used through method chaining (I highly recommend reading [this post](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining) about method chaining).

```py
np.random.seed(10); a = np.random.randint(0, 20, (3, 2))
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df
        0   1
             
    0   9   4
    1  15   0
    2  17  16
df.rename_axis(columns='A', index='B')
    A   0   1
    B        
    0   9   4
    1  15   0
    2  17  16
```

And the resulting dataframe can be further used for method chaining such as in the following:

```py
df.rename_axis(columns='A', index='B').stack('A')

    B  A
    0  0     9
       1     4
    1  0    15
       1     0
    2  0    17
       1    16
```